# How to pass through Namespace aliases to included files

Tags: php

I have a php file which defines some Namespace aliases at the start like so:

```
use Root\Something\Somethingelse\SomeClass as Alias1;

class SomeViewController {...}
```

Later at some point the class includes a template file in which i would like to use the aliased class, but i have to redefine the Alias1 again:

In the included file:

```
new Alias1; //throws error
new Root\Something\Somethingelse\SomeClass; //works as expected
```

Or if i redefine it works as well:

```
use Root\Something\Somethingelse\SomeClass as Alias1;
new Alias1; //works as well
```

Is there a way around this?

Comment: In your example you first defined `Alias1` and later you do `Alias` without the 1?

Comment: its a type-o, edited